# R: How do I call specific columns in data frame pipe?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

I'm trying to reconstruct the following expression as a pipe:

```
df <- aggregate(df1, by = list(df1$id), FUN = "mean", simplify = FALSE, drop = FALSE)
df[,5:10]=as.numeric(unlist(df[,5:10])
```

I've tried something like this:

```
df <- aggregate(df, by = list(df$id), FUN = "mean", simplify = FALSE, drop = FALSE) %>%
[,5:10]=as.numeric(unlist(df[,5:10])
```

However, It only returns an error message.

Comment: If you are using `%>%` , then whynot use `dplyr` group by operation which is more flexible and bug free compared to `aggregate` i.e. `df1 %>% group_by(id) %>% summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean, na.rm = TRUE), .groups = 'drop') %>% mutate(across(5:10, as.numeric))`

Comment: The `as.numeric` after the operation is not clear as the `mean` will be returning numeric columns

Comment: You're a champ @akrun. Thanks!